# Banner advertisement inserted into all browsers

Tags: browser, malware

My friend asked me to remove illegal banner ads inserted into all his computer's browsers. After  looking at his browsers addons, remove them and reinstall them, I still cannot figure out what causes problems.
Could you give me some suggestions for this. I don't really want to use aggressive approach to remove all browsers and reinstall them.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the question should be ask here but try to delete them with [Malwarebytes](http://www.malwarebytes.org/)

Comment: Hi Roadrish, thanks for your answer. However I care more about what causes the problem here.

Comment: After the analysis there will certainly be a long list and reason of what causes the problem x)